# CollectionView cell separators not appearing when using RxSwift

Tags: ios, swift, rx-swift, material-components, rxdatasources

The CollectionView cells' separators are not appearing when I populate the Collection View using RxSwift. I'm using RxDataSources instead of the class functions. I believe the function `drawSeparatorIfNeeded` isn't being called somewhere along the way, is there any workaround for this?

Collection View preparation:

```
private func prepareCollectionView() {
  styler.cellStyle = .card
  styler.separatorLineHeight = 3.0
  styler.separatorColor = UIColor(hex: "#eeeeee")
  styler.shouldHideSeparators = false
  collectionView?.backgroundColor = UIColor(hex: "#eeeeee")
  collectionView?.register(MDCCollectionViewTextCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: "eventCell")

  collectionView?.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

  collectionView?.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: navigationBar.bottomAnchor).isActive = true
  collectionView?.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leftAnchor).isActive = true
  collectionView?.rightAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.rightAnchor).isActive = true
  collectionView?.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor).isActive = true

  collectionView?.layoutIfNeeded()
}
```

Cell configuration:

```
dataSource.configureCell = { _, collectionView, indexPath, model in
  let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "eventCell", for: indexPath) as! MDCCollectionViewTextCell
  cell.textLabel?.text = model
  cell.backgroundColor = .white
  return cell
}
```

Cell binding:

```
Observable.just(sections)
  .bindTo(collectionView!.rx.items(dataSource: dataSource))
  .addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

Inspecting the CollectionView in Reveal shows that the separator UIImageView has a height of 0, but when I use vanilla DataSource methods, it works as expected.

Comment: Would you mind showing what your code looks like right now?

Comment: @iwillnot updated my question

Comment: @Ahmad did you manage to solve this? I'm running into the exact same problem with MDCCollectionView + RxDataSources. Thanks!

Comment: hey @t0day, sorry I never ended up solving it, for my immediate need I didn't use RxDataSources for that view controller